# Asking for HealthKit permissions after a user closes the app

Tags: swift, ios8, healthkit

Is it possible to request for HealthKit permissions for an app after a user exits the application? I have tried to solve this myself however as there is very little HealthKit documentation I have found it near impossible to find an answer. Has anyone been able to do this or anything similar?

Answer (score 2):

The authorization view is presented within the context of your app, so it is only visible when your app is in the foreground.

There is quite a bit of documentation actually, have you looked at [developer.apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/healthkit/)?